# Variable Doesn't Change in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I can't change the variable `qty` in my computed properties.

```
getQuantity(){

                return (qtyId) =>  {

                    var qty = 0;
                    axios.get( window.location.origin + '/api/quantity/' + qtyId)
                    .then(res => {
                        console.log(res.data.qty)
                        qty = res.data.qty
                    })
                    .catch()

                    console.log(qty)
                    return qty

                }
            },
```

It is an asynchronous request using axios. the `console.log(res.data.qty)` works fine it output `4` but the `console.log(qty)` is `0`. I think it's because of asynchronous request... How can I make it work... TY

Answer (score 0):

> I think it's because of asynchronous request

It definitely is.

If you're not familiar with writing asynchronous code, I would read up on that first (in particular promises).

`console.log(qty)` returns 0 because that code is executed immediately after the request is sent and before the response has come back from the server. The callback function you passed to `then` is the function that will be executed once the response has come back from the server, and only then will you be able to obtain `qty` from the response data.

If you want to return `qty` from that function (which is what it looks like you are trying to do), then that function must return a promise that once resolved will contain the `qty` value (code isn't blocked in JavaScript, hence the reason for the promise).

```js
getQuantity() {
  return (qtyId) => {
    return axios.get(window.location.origin + '/api/quantity/' + qtyId)
    .then(res => {
      return res.data.qty;
    });
  }
},
```

Why is it a computed property instead of a method? I think a different approach would be better, but I don't know exactly how this code fits into your project.

Comment: I loop it here is the code `tr v-for="(productableMerchant, index) in product.productable_merchants">
        <td>{{ productableMerchant.name}}</td>
        <td>Brand</td>
        <td>{{ productableMerchant.pivot.price}}</td>
        <td>{{ getQuantity(productableMerchant.pivot.quantity_id) }}</td>
        <td>{{ productableMerchantDisc(index) }}</td>
        <td>{{ productableMerchant.pivot.created_at}}</td>
        <td>`

Comment: And this one... `<td>{{ getQuantity(productableMerchant.pivot.quantity_id) }}</td>`

Comment: If you don't have the data upfront, you shouldn't be trying to render it in the template like you are (I don't even think Vue supports this). You should fetch the data from the server first (and display a loading spinner or something during this time), *then* once you have obtained the data you can render it.